# Skipping acquire of configured file in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, sudo, postgresql

I have recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and I am a bit fresh user for ubuntu. after installing postgresql 12 I ran `sudo apt-get update` it says

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I have no idea how to solve this! 
can anybody help me solve this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not answered in the other question for me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The definition for your `apt.postgresql.org` repo is defined in one of two possible places. Let's find it...

**In `terminal`...**

`sudo grep -i postgresql /etc/apt/sources.list`

or

`sudo grep -i postgresql /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

You'll get a hit on one of the above commands.

**Let's edit the file...**

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` (ignore any warning messages)

or

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/found_filename.list` (ignore any warning messages)

**Find the line that starts with...**

```
deb https://blah blah blah
```

**And change it to...**

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://blah blah blah
```

Save the file and quit the editor.

Now `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` will run without the noise.

Comment: I had the same issue with qgis.  Changing `deb https://qgis.org/debian focal main` to `deb [arch=amd64] https://qgis.org/debian focal main` solved my issue with "skipping acquire of configured file..."

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 installing Postgres 13 using the following guide https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-13-on-ubuntu/ thanks!

Comment: so, what's happening? I'm not updating my PostgreSQL anymore?

Comment: @senaps Who said anything about not updating? Please start a new question if you're having a problem.

Comment: @heynnema no I don't have a problem. I just fixed my update problem using your solution and thought that it will try for a [arch=amd64] version and silently ignores it if not found.

Comment: @senaps adding [arch=amd64] just limits searching for updates to 64-bit applications,  as the source doesn't support 32-bit versions, and reports updates if found.

Comment: If you already have a section with `[]` in the line, add the entry as a comma within the existing brackets. eg, `deb [signed-by=/xxxxxxx, arch=amd64]  https://......]`