# Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xx/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, multiarch

Getting this error message for VS Code while executing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]   
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic InRelease                    
Hit:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]    
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [915 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [38.7 kB]
Hit:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [42.1 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [669 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [301 kB]                                                 
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [273 kB]                                             
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]                                          
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,968 B]                                          
Fetched 2,504 kB in 20s (123 kB/s)                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Show us the complete output of the command `uname -p`

Comment: output of `uname -p`:  x86_64

Comment: See my accepted answer from yesterday at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230969/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts/1231007#1231007

Comment: Thanks. That worked

Comment: sudo sed -i 's/,arm64,armhf//g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list

Answer (score 1):

Your output ("x86_64") indicates that you are running a 64-bit operating system.

The Notification applies only to certain 32-bit (i386-architecture) operating systems.

Ignore it.

Comment: But I am not getting updates because of it. Should I try to reinstall vs code? noob here

Comment: It's not an error message. It's NOT preventing upgrades. An E: (error) message would indeed stop apt...but a N: (notification) is not a terminal error. So far everything you have shown us is expected behavior. Please edit your question to show ful output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x this question is like mine but for chrome