# How to fix skipping acquire of configured file in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: updates, 22.04

When I run sudo apt-get update, I get the following errors:

```
Hit:1 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:4 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                    
Hit:5 http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:6 http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                            
Hit:7 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Hit:12 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                                                                                                  
Hit:13 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.bachman/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.bachman' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'oem/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'oem' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/dists/any/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

My system specs are:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

and:

```
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  16
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-15
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900K @ 3.50GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               167
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            1
    CPU max MHz:         5300,0000
    CPU min MHz:         800,0000
    BogoMIPS:            7008.00
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonsto
                         p_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3d
                         nowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx51
                         2ifma clflushopt intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpcl
                         mulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid fsrm md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   384 KiB (8 instances)
  L1i:                   256 KiB (8 instances)
  L2:                    4 MiB (8 instances)
  L3:                    16 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

How can I resolve the above update issues? I do not want to remove the offending repos because I may need maintenance software from them. Is there a way to resolve these issues without having to remove or delete the offending repos?

Comment: Your output clearly says `doesn't have the component 'oem'` over and over and over. Please edit your question to show us the COMPLETE output of `sudo apt update`. If you added some kind of OEM source, please explain in your question above.

Comment: @user535733 I edited the question to provide the full "sudo apt update" ouput ... any thoughts?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1230969, https://askubuntu.com/q/1121069